# How to get T of IEnumerable<T> type parameter w/o variable?

Tags: c#, generics, type-parameter

Given:

```
public T Get<T>() { ... }
```

where `T` is closed to `IEnumerable<XYZ>`, how can I determine the `XYZ` type?

I have no variable to start with.

Comment: You mean : `TReturn = Get()` TReturn is ALWAYS `IEnumberable<XYZ>` and you need to find type of `XYZ`?

Comment: Do you mean: `class Foo<XYZ> : IEnumerable<XYZ> { public T Get<T>() { ... } where T : IEnumerable<XYZ>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the TypeSystem.GetElementType Method from [LINQ: Building an IQueryable Provider - Part I](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/07/30/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-i.aspx) to get `typeof(XYZ)` when given `typeof(IEnumerable<XYZ>)`:

```
var elementType = TypeSystem.GetElementType(typeof(IEnumerable<XYZ>));
// elementType == typeof(XYZ)
```

In your method, you can use `typeof(T)` to get the [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) object that represents `T`.

```
public T Get<T>()
{
    var elementType = TypeSystem.GetElementType(typeof(T));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `typeof(T)`, that will get you the right type info.